# Testcafe Selector functions, how do they work?

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, testcafe

When u have a selector and some functions chained

```
Selector('[data-testid="somevalue"]')
      .nth(0)
      .find('div')
      .withAttribute('class', 'someclass');
```

Does this work as a single query on dom or does it query for first one ( Selector ) and go through dom programatically there on?

I want understand this because I have a Selector that fails and I need to verify that with dom.

[image: code]

Selector

```
Selector('[data-testid="table-row"]')
      .nth(0)
      .find('div')
      .withAttribute('class', 'checkbox-ui');
```

[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the checkbox-ui class seems to be one among other classes (and it is not the first class in the list regarding the order) within the div-container that you're trying to select, you could follow the following approach to select the div properly:

```js
Selector('[data-testid="table-row"]')
      .nth(0)
      .find('div[class*="checkbox-ui"]')
```

The withAttribute method goes for a [**strict match** when Strings are used](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402742/reference/test-api/selector/withattribute). Hence, your current Selector is not able to match the div.

Regarding the * CSS-Selector, you can take a further look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/#the-seven-different-types).

Comment: Glad to hear that!

Answer (score 0):

In TestCafe v2.4.0 it's much easier to experiment with selectors thanks to the [Visual Selector Debugger](https://testcafe.io/documentation/404288/guides/intermediate-guides/visual-selector-debugger). To use it, pause the test anywhere with `await t.debug()` and find the Debug Selector panel above the TestCafe status bar.